# How Can I Prevent the Enter keypress from Triggering a Button Click?

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-8, event-propagation

I have the following code snippet.

```
  $("#days").keypress(function(e){
      if(e.keyCode == 13){
         self.validateNightModalForm();
      }
  });
```

basically, it checks for enter then invoke a function.

My only problem is that IE8 also clicks a button. When I hit enter. I've checked it with all other browsers, but only IE8 does this.

Is there any way to prevent it?

Comment: Do you mean `e.stopPropagation()` ? Without a working example it's pretty hard to tell what's going wrong. What does it mean that `IE8 also clicks a button`?

Comment: Do you mean that IE8 also dispatches a click event?

Comment: @davin, Felix Kling // I have an example page. http://qacode.com/test.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding those two lines:

```
if (e.keyCode == 13) {
    self.validateNightModalForm();
    e.preventDefault()
    return false;
}
```

Hopefully this will stop the keypress event from "going up" and trigger the form submit.